# Centering issues with large backgrounds

Tags: html, css

After a long long while I had to do some frontend, and I have a annoying issue to resolve.

So basically I have 1900x1200 Div wrapper and while the whole thing looks pretty and centered on huge monitors, when I open it on a small/resolution monitor it isn't centered.

I would like the opening position to be in the middle of the whole thing regardless of my resolution.

Any ideas?

The whole thing is driving me nuts and I can't seem to be able to wrap my head around it. :(

(and I'm sorry if I don't make much sense, its 2:25 am here, I'm not a native speaker and my brain is fizzling out)

Comment: You might be able to do it with JavaScript, but not with pure HTML/CSS. Perhaps looking into percentage-based widths instead of pixel widths would be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could center the div through absolute positioning.

```
#DivWrapper {
    width: 1900px;
    height: 1200px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -950px;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/AXenC/

Comment: as long as all the ancestor nodes of DivWrapper are statically positioned this should work (otherwise position:fixed should be used).

Comment: Oh damn *Facepalm*, I was starring at basically finished uncentered work for 2hours now and couldn't get it Thanks. :)

Comment: For your consideration: Let's say your user's browser window is 1024 pixels wide. This means that `left: 50%` calculates to `512px`. When the 950px negative margin is applied, that means that 438 pixels worth of content is off the left edge of the window, and thus invisible and inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

If your interface is base on a smaller width than 1900px probably more like a 960 grid, you could center your background in in the body tag and center the wrapper(width of your content ie: 960 px) with the margin auto on the left and right.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #aeaeae url(../images/back__v_1.jpg) 50%;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```